# asp.net mvc servicestack ormlite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ormlite-servicestack

I'm starting with ASP.NET MVC, I come from Webforms. I'm using Servicestack ormlite, and I really feel very comfortable with that ORM for the data access layer.

At this moment when I need to involve with MVC, I see(this is my opinion) it comes with Entity Framework 6 and a lot of stuff I can take advantage of MVC 5, and I ask you if I must use EF for simplicity(ie dont use third party component) or I can still use SStack, I dont have at this moment the enough expertise for choice the solution for my next project, or if it is correct to mix ASP.NET MVC with SStack (so I see in SStack web page it can replace ASP.NET MVC).

For the "model and controller" in Webforms I have in SStack a separate assembly(so I can use it-my DAL- and share with other projects), and in the MVC I dont see how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Service stack has an MVC solution as well.
See: http://mono.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/

You do not have to use Entity Framework, you're free to use any ORM you want, be it Dapper/OrmLite it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

### ServiceStack.Razor

You can use ServiceStack on its own which includes support for [Razor Views and Content Pages](http://razor.servicestack.net/) or you can use [ServiceStack with MVC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) which lets you [call ServiceStack Services directly from MVC controllers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration).

### API First Development

An [API-first development](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts#razor-pages) approach provides a friction-free development experience which encourages maximum re-use where you can get [auto form binding and validation](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts#bootstrap-forms) with 1-line of JavaScript that lets you re-use the same ServiceStack Services to also provide [structured validation errors](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation) for Mobile and Desktop Apps as well.

### Data-driven Websites and Services with ServiceStack with OrmLite

The simplest solution would be just using ServiceStack and [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) on its own which works with clean POCOs and only requires [1-line of configuration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#usage) which would then lets you use [AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) which lets you create fully query-able REST Services with just a single Request DTO.

ServiceStack's [Northwind Demo](http://northwind.servicestack.net/) shows examples of creating data-driven Services with OrmLite and AutoQuery.